# why is video tag not running on homepage?

Tags: html, video, autoplay

I have a video on the background of my homepage, on desktop the video runs smoothly with its autoplay and loop attributes, the problem is that on mobile when the loads the homepage ("www.website.com") the video doesn't run, the space is used but the video is not playing.

If you change page on the menu to "www.website.com/aboutus" and return to the homepage which loads "www.website.com/index.html" the video does play.

what do i need to do for the video to load on both pages or is there a way to load directly the one with de index.html to always load and play the homepage video?

My video tag is placed like this

```
<video autoplay muted loop class="video2">
        <source src="assets/imagenes/video/video.mp4" type="video/mp4" >
      </video>
```

Comment: Hi! If you show the code you are using people can help you easily

Answer (score 0):

I have answered it yestered as well for someone having the same sort of issue.
As per Google Autoplay [Policy](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes)

- Muted autoplay is always allowed.
- Autoplay with sound is allowed if:
  User has interacted with the domain (click, tap, etc.). On desktop,
  the user's Media Engagement Index threshold has been crossed, meaning
  the user has previously play video with sound. On mobile, the user
  has [added the site to their home screen].
- Top frames can delegate
  autoplay permission to their iframes to allow autoplay with sound.

When user change page on the menu to "www.website.com/aboutus" and return to the homepage, it is kind of cheat that browsers treats as user intervention.

Comment: hi thank you very much, i already knew about the muted autoplay so i had it muted from the begining but still is not working as intended, i dont require sound just the video played on the background

Comment: @WarkarianRagnashark which browser version is having that issue?

Comment: latest mobile version of chrome on android

Comment: try with playsinline <video playsinline autoplay muted loop class="video2">

Comment: Also can you check the version of android chrome? There was the launch bug in earlier versions https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=618000